# Is it possible to apply Ant filters when running the Ant jar task

Tags: ant, jar

The Ant jar task documentation mentions nothing about filtering.  Is it possible to apply Ant filtering when running the jar task, if so how?

Comment: By "filtering" you mean specifying what files to include/exclude based on wildcards?

Comment: No, by 'filtering' I mean replacing text of the form @....@ with values from a properties file.